# SASS and Prepross: git does not detect changes in processed .css file

Tags: git, sass, prepros

Hello I'm using Prepros 6.1.1 as a preprocessor for my SASS files. Everything works fine but my git does not detect changes to the processed .css file when I make changes in .sass file and compile it with Prepros. When I do "git status" after changes in .sass, all I get is "modified:   prepros-6.config". So essentially git misses both .sass and .css files for some reason. Now I have 2 different version of those files on dev and live environments.

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I fix the difference between those files now that hey are different on live and dev environments?

Thank you very much

Comment: P.s. SASS compiles just fine - I can see changes made on my dev environment. But I just cannot push those changes to production since git fails to identify them.

Comment: Can you make sure that you're not ignoring the files?

Comment: 100% not ignoring. I can see them if I put H css/custom.css "git ls-files" and checked .gitignore file

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to fix this problems. Apparently this issue was caused by the .config file that Prepros creates. All I did was: went to the Settings on Prepros, and on "general" tab there is a n option to "export Config" and untick that. Now after compiling .sass and checking with git status I can see changes in both .sass and .css .

Not sure how hat config file prevents git from seeing changes in files if anyone has a clue would be interesting to know just for learning purposes.

Cheers!